# Move div down smoothly while updating in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I was trying to make a list that updates from the top. Every time when new list item is inserted, old items will be moved down together smoothly

So firstly I generate list item every time I click

```
function addItem(){ 
 $('#public').prepend('<li><div id="item' + i + '" class="tile"></div></li>');
 $('#item' + i).fadeIn();                                        
 i ++}
```

then I tried to animate() them down by using the code below:

```
 $('.tile').animate({top:42},500);
```

Strangely, only the last element will animate down smoothly, other elements will still be squashed down. And there is always 42px white between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where the variable i gets initialized? I mean, does it increment since you don't pass the variable in the method or retrieve the current value from somewhere. I don't think you need to use the variable anyhow by the way. You can use jQuery to get all siblings and than call the animate on that list of items (of course with an if statement that skips the latest added item).

Comment: Thanks. The variable is outside this method. You can check the demo code for details.

To get all siblings, actually $('.tile') kinda get them all. Since every item has that class. But they don't get animated except the last one. That's why I feel strange.

Comment: Maybe you must loop through all items (.each) and call the animate method on the items one by one. Just a wild guess.